# Plot two dataframes with same formats on same graph but only one graph per column

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, matplotlib

I have two dataframes, `df_iter_actuals` and `df_iter_preds` that look like this:

```
cohort  FGCI 0.0 2017   FGCI 1.0 2020   FGCI 1.0 2021
Month_Next          
2022-04-01  1.207528    10.381440   4.332759
2022-05-01  1.529364    1.649636    5.007991
2022-06-01  21.715032   7.491215    6.096792
2022-07-01  0.958635    12.460808   5.759696
2022-08-01  25.637608   0.961132    4.635855
2022-09-01  0.997071    0.721632    3.799172
2022-10-01  27.006847   0.811228    3.586541
```

```
cohort  FGCI 0.0 2017   FGCI 1.0 2020   FGCI 1.0 2021
Month_Next          
2022-04-01  16.804628   5.143954    3.296097
2022-05-01  16.804628   5.143954    3.193598
2022-06-01  16.804628   5.143954    3.066248
2022-07-01  16.804628   5.143954    2.907984
2022-08-01  16.804628   5.143954    2.711235
2022-09-01  16.804628   5.143954    2.466544
2022-10-01  16.804628   5.143954    2.162079
```

One is the actual values and the other is the predicted values for a certain time series data set. I'd like to plot the shared columns between the two dataframes on a single plot, but creating a new plot for each column. For example, I'd like the data for `FGCI 0.0 2017` to be shown on the same plot as line graphs for both dfs, and then for the next plot showing the data for `FGCI 1.0 2020.` I was able to accomplish this with just one dataframe with

```py
for i in df_iter_actuals.columns:
    plt.figure(figsize = (10,8))
    plt.plot(df_iter[i])
    plt.title(f'Pct Error of CPR Predictions for {i}')
```

But I don't know how to do it with two dataframes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the format/column name is the same for both df, you can just call them :

```
for i in df_iter_actuals.columns:
    plt.figure(figsize = (10,8))
    plt.plot(df_iter_actuals[i])
    plt.plot(df_iter_preds[i])
    plt.title(f'Pct Error of CPR Predictions for {i}')
```

Comment: This answer had the best output in terms of legend access

Answer (score 0):

```
# Create figure and axes
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 8))

# Iterate over columns in dataframes
for col in df_iter_actuals.columns:
    # Use the `df.plot()` function to plot the column from each dataframe
    df_iter_actuals[col].plot(ax=ax, label="Actual")
    df_iter_preds[col].plot(ax=ax, label="Predicted")

    # Set the title of the plot to the column name to whatever you need
    ax.set_title(f"Pct Error of CPR Predictions for {col}")
    
    # Show the plot and legend
    ax.legend()
    plt.show()
```

Just iterate over the columns of your two dataframes and then use the `df.plot()` function to plot each column from both dataframes on the same graph figure!

Answer (score 0):

You can [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) and use [`groupby.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.plot.html):

```
(pd.concat([df_iter_actuals, df_iter_preds], keys=['actual', 'pred'], axis=1)
   .groupby(level=1, axis=1).plot()
)
```